# Как хранить зависимости в go lang?

Tags: golang, golang-faq

Недавно начал изучать этот язык, и написал небольшое веб приложение на `revel` фреймфорке и тепер стал вопрос как хранить зависимости в `git`?
Хранить все зависимости - мне кажется это странным, можно ли как то сделать так что бы все зависимости сохранялись в папку vendor или что то подобное (как в `PHP` например)?

Comment: *"как хранить зависимости в git"* -- а зачем?

Comment: @D-side Наверное я не правильно  написал вопрос. - Проведу аналогию с php - там есть файл package.json в котором описаны все зависимости и при команде composer install все пакеты ставятся. Насколько я понял в go такого нет.  Когда я ставлю сторонний пакет он ставится рядом с моим проектом - и на етапе сохранения в гит своего проекта мне нужно в git ignore добавить все сторонние пакеты что бы и гите их небыло - это в go нормальный подход?

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас наиболее популярным (насколько мне известно) является инструмент [dep](https://github.com/golang/dep). Он создаёт файл `Gopkg.lock`, в котором указаны точные версии/хэши комитов ваших зависимостей.

Добавлять `/vendor` в ваш проект или нет - дело ваше. Во многих проектах их сохраняют, чтобы сборку всегда можно было легко воспроизвести и внешние проблемы (например, блокировка Гитхаба Роскомнадзором) не ломали CI.

Answer (score 0):

В `Go` все работает от `$GOPATH` в локальной реализации вашего проекта, он будет хранить все зависимости в деректории `Vendor` но для `git` репозиториев, это плохой тон, и лучше иметь файл конфигурации `$GOPATH` чтобы тот уже на уникальной машине при компиляции скачивал все зависимости в `Vendor`, а все зависимости при создании `Git` Репозитория заносить в `gitignore`, этот подход использует не только `Go` но и `PHP` и другие.

В `Go` кстати, с недавних пор появился полноценный пакет менеджер.

Comment: у меня все зависимости ставятся в папку src, рядом с моим проектом - как сделать что бы они были в отдельной папке **Vendor**?

Comment: Читайте подробнее про `GOPATH` в локальном репозитории.